# Revealing Prototype 'this' context

Tags: javascript, revealing-prototype

I'm trying to demonstrate the Revealing Prototype Pattern in jsfiddle with the sample below; however, the alert always displays "undefined" instead of the value provided in the object instance I created on document ready. I took this from the example provided by [Dan Wahlin's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-prototype-pattern) but can't seem to figure out why the value of id is undefined. I figure it has something to do with the context of 'this' changing but not sure how? Thanks.

```
foo = window.foo || {}
foo.User = function(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = "Bob";    
};
foo.User.prototype = function(){
    var showUser = function(thisObj){alert(thisObj.id);};
    var showUserPublic = function(){showUser(this);};
    return{
            showUser : showUserPublic()   
    };
}();



$(function(){
    var newUser = new foo.User("bob123");
    newUser.showUser();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showUser : showUserPublic()` *calls* `showUserPublic` and assigns its return value (`undefined`) to the property `showUser`. If you want to expose `showUserPublic` as the `showUser` method on the prototype, just use the function name without `()`:

```
return{
        showUser : showUserPublic
};
```

When that's called by your `newUser.showUser();` line, `this` will be the user object during the call to `showUserPublic`, which passes it on to `showUser` as an argument. (I don't know why you're doing it indirectly like that, but I expect you do have a reason.)

---

Side note:

I recommend **not** replacing the default `prototype` object, but instead *augmenting* it. This avoids pitfalls related to timing. It's a small change:

```
(function(p){
    var showUser = function(thisObj){alert(thisObj.id);};
    p.showUser = function(){showUser(this);};
}(foo.User.prototype);
```

---

Side note 2:

Separately, the code seems to rely on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring `foo`. You can change the first line to:

```
var foo = foo || {};
```

How that works:

Because of [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html), that really boils down to:

```
var foo;
foo = foo || {};
```

If there is already a declared variable called `foo`, the `var foo` bit is a no-op; it has absolutely no effect (and in particular, no effect on the current value of `foo`). Then the next line is straightforward: If `foo` is falsey, we assign `{}` to it.

---

Putting the side notes together with the main answer:

```
var foo = foo || {}
foo.User = function(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = "Bob";    
};
(function(p){
    var showUser = function(thisObj){alert(thisObj.id);};
    p.showUser = function(){showUser(this);};
}(foo.User.prototype);


$(function(){
    var newUser = new foo.User("bob123");
    newUser.showUser();
});
```